# Facebook login with particular id and default login to particular user

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I created  a custom application in facebook. And I did my upload section in facebook.
If I upload the picture it created a album in existing user that he logged in.
How to upload the file to my particular profile in facebook.

- For ex : my face book  login
- username  :test@Facebook
- password : test

I upload the picture from my website it want to upload in my above user. If any help appreciate.